# How to migrate large data volume from On-premise to Heroku Postgres

Tags: heroku, data-migration, largedatavolumes

We are planning to migrate large volume of data from on-premise Oracle DB to Heroku Postgres in Private Space. We are using Heroku to build our API Services for various channels e.g. portal / mobile

The data volume is about 200 millions. How can we tackle this? We are exploring options like pg_restore via CLI or Xplenty but not sure about the performance.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

(ed note: Heroku is a Salesforce product; Heroku Support is asking customers to come here to ask Heroku-specific questions.)

Comment: This is not off-topic, as it is asking specifically about data import with Heroku Postgres (a Salesforce product). Please re-open.

Comment: Don't agree it is off-topic. Anyway, just want to share our solution for the benefit of those who may have similar questions. Heroku Support recommended pgloader however we did not choose it since we cannot find a stable windows version. We managed to migrate 400+ million records into heroku using PgAdmin. The performance benchmark is around 40 minutes for 10 million records with around 8 columns.